# Why is the turtlebot gazebo kinect not in color?

Tags: gazebo, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed that the kinect sensor in turtlebot_gazebo (in the unstable release) produces only black and white images.  The gazebo.urdf.xacro file looks like it is supposed to produce color.  Also, gazebo_ros_openni_kinect.cpp looks like it should be producing color.  Are there plans to get the kinect gazebo working in color soon?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11505/why-is-the-turtlebot-gazebo-kinect-not-in-color?/) by [sdavies](https://answers.ros.org/users/406/sdavies/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2011-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It actually is in color, it just turns the pixels that are beyond the maximum depth of the kinect sensor to a gray color.

---

Originally posted by [sdavies](https://answers.ros.org/users/406/sdavies/) with karma: 88 on 2011-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0